# Assign new values to levels in R

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

all,

I have a large data set (over 2 million rows), and in one of the columns I have the following levels:

```
"0"     "0.001" "1"     "4"     "4.001" "8.001"
```

I want to make a new column where each of those has a new, corresponding letter:

0 = x, 0.001 = D, 1 = C, 4 and 4.001 = B, and 8.001 = A

Is there a way to do this without using a for loops with 6 if statements? I tried that, and it was taking forever to run.

Here's a test sample:

```
      a b
1 0.000 x
2 4.000 B
3 1.000 C
4 0.001 D
5 1.000 C
6 4.000 B
7 4.001 B
8 1.000 C
9 8.001 A
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you meant that one of the **columns** had the levels which you provided. If you really meant rows then my solution does not apply. In fact I will then not even be sure of what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right. My apologies for that. I have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a single line command that can do it for you. BTW `for` loops by nature are inefficient and not recommended for large data sets.

**Option 1:**
What you may want to try is `logical indexing` which is a statistical implementation of [bit array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array).

```
idx<- df$a == "0.000"
df$NewColumn[idx] <- "x"

idx<- df$a == "4.000"
df$NewColumn[idx] <- "B"
```

and so on and so forth...

**Option 2:**
Use `plyr` and `revalue` which is a simpler implementation however could be more compute intensive than option 1. Should still easily work for your data size.

```
library(plyr)
df$NewColumn <- revalue(df$a, c(0 = "x", 0.001 = "D", 1 = "C", 4 = "B", 4.001 = "B", and 8.001 = "A"))
```

For either option, make sure that the data type `class` is provided correctly. From your example, its hard for me to tell if the data is `factor` or `numeric` but either ways, its a simple change to manage in my sample code.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to create a key/value dataset and join with the original data

```
keyval <- data.frame(a = c(0, 0.001, 1, 4, 4.001, 8.001), 
     b = c('x', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A'), stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[keyval, b := b, on = .(a)]
df1
#       a b
#1: 0.000 x
#2: 4.000 B
#3: 1.000 C
#4: 0.001 D
#5: 1.000 C
#6: 4.000 B
#7: 4.001 B
#8: 1.000 C
#9: 8.001 A
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(0, 4, 1, 0.001, 1, 4, 4.001, 1, 8.001)), 
    .Names = "a", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as.factor (x, levels=c (whatever levels and values separated by comma))

Answer (score 0):

I would try this, not shure about the runtime though:

```
library(forcats)
df = data.frame(a = c("0", "0.001", "1", "4", "4.001", "8.001"))
df$b <- fct_recode(df$a,
               X = "0",
               D = "0.001",
               C = "1",
               B = "4",
               B = "4.001",
               A = "8.001")
```

[image]